# FAILED_RETRYING_INTERNAL when setting up managed security

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a google managed certificate for my app engine project, I've verified the domain on the web master's toolbox, I've got DNS set up and pointing correctly, but the spinner never stops for days.

[image: spinner spinning forever]

I've tried removing and re-adding the domain and managed security.

From the console running `gcloud alpha app ssl-certificates list` shows `FAILED_RETRYING_INTERNAL` (the beta and regular version of the command just show nothing), the only documentation I've been able to find relating to that error is [this comment](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/20530fd5d65ad2caee87891f9896d7547cb400c9/appengine/v1alpha/appengine-gen.go#L761-L764) which implies it's a transient error which should not be going on over night.

Other things of note: this is a subdomain for a .edu (i.e. oursite.university.edu) and it seems like other departments are using lets encrypt as well.

Comment: Did you try to approach the support? They will have access to more information which may be necessary to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

- Get the ID of the certificate with this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/ssl-certificates/list):
  `gcloud beta app ssl-certificates list`
- Create the custom domain mapping with said ID with [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/domain-mappings/create):
  `gcloud beta app domain-mappings create YOUR_DOMAIN --certificate-id=YOUR_CERTIFICATE_ID`

If the error persists, since this should be a transient error, it would be a good idea to move this issue to [Support for Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/), as mentioned by the user in the comments.